# Environment variable undefined in test/syst/prod - Angular v12+Ocp4 config map

Tags: angular, environment-variables, openshift

I have Angular frontend and I need to access environment variable based on test, stage, prod.
[I have used this solution](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/setup-dotenv-to-access-environment-variables-in-angular-9-f06c6ffb86c0). Localy it picks up variable from .env file correctly, but when going through pipeline to test/stage/prod, variable from openshift config map is not picked up and is set to string "undefined" (process.env. vars work fine in backend though).

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Angular's default env files are not a viable solution for now, need a temp fix.

Comment: do you really need the solution with dotenv? Are you sure you can't use Angular's default environment files?

Comment: I need a faster solution for now. Pipeline is setup with templates so I cant build with different configurations and it would take time to redo whole process.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this library. [ng-process-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-process-env)

It is based on angular schematics and allows you to replace values in your `environment.config.ts` file with relevant values from `process.env`